# Using ItemDecorator to make separators in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, draw, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use `ItemDecorator` to add some separators into a `RecyclerView`. This is the fragment of the code that does it.

```
//...
public abstract C onInflateViewHolder(Context ctx);

public abstract void onBindViewHolder(C holder, int index);

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        C view = onInflateViewHolder(mContext);
        onBindViewHolder(view, i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //parent.addView(view.itemView, i, p);
        view.itemView.draw(c);
    }
}
//...
```

As you can see I tried using `parent.addView(view.itemView, i, p);`, `parent.addView(view.itemView, i);` and finally `view.itemView.draw(c);`.

This is the implementations:

```
mItemDecorator =
                new GenericDecorator<ChatDateSeparatorViewHolder>(getActivity(), GenericDecorator.VERTICAL_LIST) {
                    @Override
                    public ChatDateSeparatorViewHolder onInflateViewHolder(Context ctx) {
                        View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.chat_message_separator, null);
                        return new ChatDateSeparatorViewHolder(v);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBindViewHolder(ChatDateSeparatorViewHolder holder, int index) {
                        if (index < mAdapter.getItemCount()-1) {
                            ChatMessage previous = mAdapter.getMessage(index);
                            ChatMessage current = mAdapter.getMessage(index+1);

                            long startTime = previous.getSendDate().getTime();
                            long endTime = current.getSendDate().getTime();
                            long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
                            long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

                            if (diffDays > 0) {
                                holder.text.setText(Converters.format(current.getSendDate(), getActivity()));
                            } else {
                                holder.root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
        };
```

By the way, C is a `Recycler.ViewHolder`, as you can see in the implementation.

All seems to be fine but It crashes when tries to add the views. The exceptions that I did get was `NullpointerException` when I used the addView with the LayoutParams ad `at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams.getViewPosition(RecyclerView.java:6957)`

I just need to know how add programatically a `View` into a `RecyclerView` without using an adapter.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to add separators in a `RecyclerView`, this separators will be views that I get from a `ViewHolder`, it's everything done, the only thing that I need to know is how add, programatically, the view (that I get from my `ViewHolder`) into the `RecyclerView`

Here is a screenshot of the mockup of the app, so you will have a better idea:

[image]

The line that says "Hoy" (today in spanish) is one of the separators.

Comment: ItemDecoration is hmm,  a decoraton so why are you doing that: view.itemView.draw(c); ?

Comment: Was just a random line of code, I tried that because I already tried with `addView(View,Index)` and `addView(View,Index,LayoutParams)`,  I did it just to give it a shot.

Comment: addView?  in ItemDecoration?  why? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question, so you will have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: why don't you make it (i mean Hoy item) a normal view that is mapped by adapter?

Comment: Because if I do that I have to change a lot of code, using an `ItemDecorator` the separators are added after the adapter's items are rendered. Also, AFAIK the `ItemDecorator` is the [way to go](https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e) when you want to implement separators.

Comment: Sure,but your separator is not a simple line but complex view... Anyway i will try to write such a decoration, stay tuned...

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/Whcue12w

Comment: but if you need more complex separators you should really "embed" them in item views, e.g. by creating the root view as a LinearLayout with two child views: separator + main view and setting the visibility of the separator depending on items' data

Comment: see that simple `RecyclerView.Adapter` http://pastebin.com/VPzrLBMx on how to do that

Comment: You oughta check out Support7Demos sample in the SDK.  It illustrates how to use RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using your item `View's` tag

In your `Adapter's` onBindViewHolder, you can determine whether or not this was the last message for the day. If it was the last message of the day, then you can call something like `holder.itemView.setTag("isLastForDay")`.

Then in your decorator, while looping through your `RecyclerView's` children, read each child's tag. If the tag contains "isLastForDay", then execute your "hoy" drawing logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i frequently do this

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    RecycleMarginDecoration recycleMarginDecoration = new RecycleMarginDecoration(this);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(recycleMarginDecoration);
```

Add Decorator Class

```
public class RecycleMarginDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int margin;

public RecycleMarginDecoration(Context context) {
  /* Assign value from xml whatever you want to make as margin*/
    margin = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_four);
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(
        Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.set(margin, margin / 2, margin / 2, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: Yup, but as I said in my question, my separators are ViewHolders how I could add them using and ItemDecoration and the xml of the view holder?

Comment: Ok, As you are taking about that **HOY** view, as far i understand that is also a view which is added not any Item-decorator. Define another type of view in getItemViewType() method in adapter   `public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (lsItem.size() == 0)
            return EMPTY_VIEW;
        /*null Indicate Loader*/
        if (lsItem.get(position) == null)
            return PROGRESS_VIEW;

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }`   this is how I created two defferent type of view in my recyclerview

Comment: Yes, that's right, that's how I solve this problem a year ago, but I was waiting someone who could tell me how to do it, not adding a different type of view in my adapter but rather adding the view with the ItemDecorator, after all this is not a different type of view, is a separator.